What are partitions of unity in surface integrals for?
In my analysis book (A Course on Analysis, vol. II, Elon Lages Lima), in chapter VII (which deals with differential forms), the author goes into details about partitions of unity and integral of forms using them. 
For example: For $\omega$ an m-form on the m-dimensional surface $M$; $\sum \xi_i = 1$ a unity partition strictly subordinate to the cover $M = \bigcup U_i$, where each $U_i$ has compact closure in $M$ and is the image of a positive parametrization $\phi: U_{i_0}\to U_i$; and  $\sum \zeta_j = 1$ a unity partition strictly subordinate to the cover $M = \bigcup V_j$, where each $V_j$ has compact closure in $M$ and is the image of a positive parametrization $\psi: V_{j_0}\to V_j$; writing $\omega_i=\omega \xi_i$ and $\overline\omega_j = \omega\zeta_j$, we have $\int_M \omega = \sum_i{\int_M \omega_i} = \sum_j{\int_M \overline\omega_j}$ - that is, the surface integral of the form does not depend on the chosen partition of the unit.
My qyestion is: what is the interest and motivation in introducing them to surface integrals? The book does not go into the context of it, and just throws it at you without explaining why it is there. I am confused as to why it is relevant (though I do not doubt it is of importance). Can someone shed a light on it for me?

Question for you, which your post does not specify very precisely: Given $M$ and $\omega$, how is the integral $\int_M \omega$ defined?

The book defines, for $\omega(x) = a(u)du_1 \wedge \dots \wedge du_m, \phi: U_0 \to U$ a parametrization with the support of $\omega$ contained in U, as  $\int_{M}{\omega} = \int_{K}{a(u)du_1 \wedge \dots \wedge du_m}$, where $K$ is s.t. $\phi^{-1}(\mathrm{supp.},\omega) \subset K \subset U_0$.

That's not the general definition of $\int_M \omega$, that's only the definition of the very special case where the support of $\omega$ happens to be a compact subset of $U$.

I conjecture the unity partitions are then a way to integrate this form when its support is not contained in a single $U \subseteq M$, but then why do we have to multiply it by the $\xi_i$ and not just "break it" into several integrals over the intersection of the support of $\omega$ and each $U_i$ of the cover?

Yes, the book first defines it in this specific way, then suddenly comes up with this definition with the unity partitions. It's rather confusing

Your last comment is not correct. That definition of $\int_M \omega$ in your comment is not the general definition, it is instead a definition of a very special case of $\int_M \omega$. That special case simply does not apply in general: it does not apply if the support of $\omega$ is not a compact subset of some coordinate neighborhood $U \subset M$.

See this recent answer of mine to address these questions of yours. Partitions of unity give a slick definition of integrals (though not fully necessary) and also a very nice proof of Stokes’ theorem which would be very cumbersome without it (I haven’t succeeded in recent times to give a general proof without partitions of unity or some other abstraction).

I see, so they are to prevent overcounting in possibly overlapping $U_i$ on the cover?

Yes. Precisely. They are a theoretical tool. In practice, we try to cover most of $M$ with one or more coordinate charts that do not overlap; if we miss only a subset of measure zero, that subset does not affect the integral.
